# JComboBox width

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, dimensions

I have created a jComboBox but it takes the full width of the frame. how to set the width fixed.

yes borderlayout for the frame and box layout for the panel.  i am adding the code here:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class Window8  {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JComboBox combo;
    public void go(){

    String[] option = { "STUDENT", "TEACHER" };

    combo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,25));
    combo = new JComboBox(option);
    menu.setSelectedIndex(0);

    frame = new JFrame("DELETION"); 
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH,panel);
    panel.add(combo);   
}
```

Comment: i have added my code. please have a look at it.

Comment: Reformatted code; copyedited; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 31):

The width is automatically determined by the width of the largest item added to the combo box. You can control the display by using:

```
comboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("text here");
```

You might also consider using the [Combo Box Popup](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/) to control the popup size.

Edit:

Since you added code that shows you are using a BoxLayout you can try the following:

```
comboBox.setMaximumSize( comboBox.getPreferredSize() );
```

Or you can do something like:

```
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.add( comboBox );
panel.add( wrapper );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to understand how these suggestions work.

Comment: Using `setPrototypeDisplayValue` with a sensitive option helps on properly resizing the JComboBox while allowing it to have a different size according to container definition. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

try comboBox.setPreferredWidth(200); or some other value to set the width

jzd is right. The actual API is `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(...));`

Comment: i tried but gives this error.                                                                " The method setPreferredWidth(int) is undefined for the type JComboBox"

Comment: Looking in the API, the exact method is: setPreferredSize(Dimension preferredSize)

Answer (score 1):

Use a different LayoutManager.  Try `FlowLayout`.

Comment: The width will be automatically determined based on the contents or use setPreferredSize() or camickr's suggestion.  But if you put it in a layout that stretches it will not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you can do with box layout.

- Change axis to line axis, Add
- horizontal glue, Add rigid area,
- place the component

.
code snippet below:

```
panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
panel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
panel.add(combo);
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, panel);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `setSize()` method.

```
combo.setSize(200, combo.getPreferredSize().height);
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use JCombobox<>() instead of that use Combobox<>() then width won't change, also if you set preferred size it won't change with Combobox so use this instead

Comment: `ComboBox` is a heavyweight AWT component.  AWT components and Swing components don't always play well together.