# Combo box + list in java

Tags: java, oracle, swing

In java how can i define a different size for the dropdown list inside the combobox. So the combobox have a size and the dropdown list another size like this:

[image: http://www.thetertulianblog.comyr.com/js/java.jpg]

Comment: I've edited my answer with something more useful. :p

Answer (score 2):

Never used Swing but what about this [post](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/)?

(Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629015/jcombobox-width))

Comment: that post is in java, what do you mean?